# jQuery で select ボックスで選択された値を取得する

Tags: javascript, jquery

[本家SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery)より自分がうまくいかなかったコードを追加して転載しています。

`jQuery` のセレクタで select ボックスで選択されている textNode の値を取得する方法が分からないです。

```
var areaSelect = $("#area");
var area = areaSelect.text()
```

とやってしまうと、ドロップダウンに含まれている値が全部選択されてしまいます。

Comment: 「値」がテキストノードなのかvalueなのかがイマイチわかりませんでしたので、両方書きましたが、できれば編集して明記していただけるといいと思います。

Comment: @ISHITOYAKentaro textNode でした。訂正しました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 5, accepted):

以下のようなhtmlがあった時、

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="area">
<option value="1">北海道</option>
<option value="2">青森</option>
<option value="3">秋田</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

optionのvalue属性の値が欲しい時は、

```
$("#area option[value=1]").val();
```

optionのtextNodeの値が欲しい時は、

```
$("#area option[value=1]").text();
```

になります。選択されているoptionをselectしたい場合は、

```
$("#area option:selected").text();
```

です。

Answer (score 1):

```
<p id="out"></p>
<select id="hogehoge">
    <option value="hoge1">hoge1</option>
    <option value="hoge2">hoge2</option>
</select>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $hogehoge=$('#hogehoge');
    $('#out').text($hogehoge.children(':eq(0)').text());
</script>
```

変数に渡しておくという前提であれば、こんなので表示は可能です。

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="area">
    <option value="1">aaa</option>
    <option value="2">bbb</option>
    <option value="3">ccc</option>
</select>
```

とした場合に $("#area").text() だと

```
    <option value="1">aaa</option>
    <option value="2">bbb</option>
    <option value="3">ccc</option>
```

を取得してしまうということでしょか

だとすればoptionの要素のtextNodeが欲しい場合は
セレクタにoption要素を追加する必要があります。
質問者様の書き方に合わせるとこんな感じでしょうか

```
var areaSelect = $("#area");
var area = areaSelect.children("option:selected").text();
```

個人的にはISHITOYA Kentaro様の書き方のほうがいいかと思います